# ExtensionNotFoundForCPUArchitecture Error while running bicep file with typeHandlerVersion 1.0

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

We are running bicep file to deploy a Ubuntu OS based VM with azureCLI and kubectl cli installed using extensions in bicep file.However, facing the below error with multiple typeHandlerVersion like 1.0, 2.0,2.4.

**{"code":"ExtensionNotFoundForCPUArchitecture","message":"Extension with publisher 'Microsoft.Azure.Extensions', type 'CustomScript', and type handler version '1.0' for CPU Architecture 'x64' was not found in the extension repository**

```
Bicep resource code:

resource azureCliExtension 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions@2021-11-01' = {
  name: '${vm.name}/installAzureCli'
  location: location
  properties: {
    publisher: 'Microsoft.Azure.Extensions'
    type: 'CustomScript'
    typeHandlerVersion: '1.0'
    autoUpgradeMinorVersion: true
    settings: {
      script: 'https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: according to the documentation, the version should be 2.1: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux

Comment: Also can you check that your linux distribution is supported for the specific CPU Arch: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-linux#supported-linux-distributions

Comment: @Jahnavi, this is ubuntu os, i have also updated my question with the OS details.

Comment: @Thomas, sure, i can try that, however,i already tried 2.4 with no luck..

Comment: Try with `2.0` or `2.1` @saurabhumathe first. It is working for me.

Comment: Yeah i dont think there is a 2.4 version anyway

Comment: and regarding ubuntu are you using one these distro version `18.04+, 20.04+, 22.04+` ?

Comment: yes. i am using 18.04+

Comment: @Jahnavi are the rest of the params are same as what i mentioned above ?

Comment: Yes rest all are correctly given. @saurabhumathe

Comment: were you able to resolve it? @saurabhumathe

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. yes it worked. @Jahnavi

Comment: Thats great. Is it worked by changing type handler version to `2.0`? @saurabhumathe

Answer (score 0):

> **{"code":"ExtensionNotFoundForCPUArchitecture","message":"Extension with publisher `'Microsoft.Azure.Extensions'`, type `'CustomScript'`, and type handler version '1.0' for CPU Architecture 'x64' was not found in the extension repository**:

The above error comes when the extension `Microsfot.Azure.Extensions`, type `'CustomScript'`, and `type handler version '1.0'` are not compatible with each other. In this scenario, you need to use a different (latest) version of the extension.

Using type `typeHandlerVersion: '2.0' or '2.1'` works for your issue.

*Modified bicep code:*

```bash
resource azureCliExtension 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions@2021-11-01' = {
  name: '${vm.name}/installAzureCli'
  location: location
  properties: {
    publisher: 'Microsoft.Azure.Extensions'
    type: 'CustomScript'
    typeHandlerVersion: '2.0' or '2.1'
    autoUpgradeMinorVersion: true
    settings: {
      script: 'https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb'
    }
  }
}
```

You can easily check the available extension versions for custom script of a VM with the below command as shown.

[`az vm extension image list`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm/extension/image?view=azure-cli-latest#az-vm-extension-image-list%28%29)

```bash
az vm extension image list --publisher Microsoft.Azure.Extensions --name CustomScript
```

[image]

[Custom script template for VM extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.compute/virtualmachines/extensions?pivots=deployment-language-bicep).